# Cast to chromecast and then keep it playing

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

im in the discovery phase of developing a sender and a receiver app for my digital signage web system.

I need to figure out if this is even possible before i continue. my digital signage is just a url that runs in a browser. everythinf is web based.

what i need is two things.

1: can i reboot (power on) the chrome cast and have it start an url? this to prevent any manual configuration.

2: can i configure multiple reeivers with their own unique url and then tun off my sender and the receivers just keeps playing?

hope it is clear what im trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you cannot do that
2. Are you using one sender to communicate with multiple receivers?? In general, you can disconnect your sender from the receiver and still set things up so that the receiver continues to play. Note that a sender can only be connected to at most one receiver at a time.